# Angular js application shows blank white page on ios browsers, safari and chrome both. Works fine on windows desktop browsers

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have one redhat cloud application which front-end  developed in Angular.js 1.5.5, it works perfectly fine on windows desktop and android device browsers where only on ios mobile browsers chrome or safari it shows blank white page. When I put sample loading text under body tag I was able to see that but nothing rendered except loadig text. To serve static content  it has Node-Hapi.js server which has just basic stuff and static folder path. 
Below is application url -

http://restperformance-gunjankrs.rhcloud.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code line

```js
let myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['blockUI']);
```

to

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['blockUI']);
```

as 'let' is not supported in strict mode on iOS and Safari.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['blockUI']);
```

Also change those:

```
var requestObj = $scope.serviceData;
    var req = {
```

Comment: Great finding, it is working on ios browsers smoothly now. You saved my day.